# Sort cts:search results by cts:score without using expicit loop

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to get results of [cts:search](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) data sorted on the basis of [cts:score](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:score). I am using following code -

```
(
        if ($direction = "descending")
        then
            for $result in cts:search (...)
            order by cts:score($result) descending
            return $result/element()
        else
            for $result in cts:search (...)
            order by cts:score($result) ascending
            return $result/element()
    )[$first-result to $last-result]
```

Is there any way out of getting results from [cts:search](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) in a sorted manner itself?

The problem with the current code is that in the case of large data set it gives **XDMP-EXPNTREECACHEFULL** error. Increasing the size of **Expanded Tree Cache** is not an option. So I need to do something in this part only.
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution to this. We can use [cts:score-order](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:score-order) option with in the [cts:search](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search)